# AES-256 / CBC encryption in Erlang & decryption in C not working

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, erlang, aes

I am facing a problem with encrypting AES 256 bit CBC in Erlang and then decrypting it in c code. Whereas Encryption/decryption works in Erlang and C but not from one to another.

```erlang
Ivec = "1200000000000000",
Key = "586E36EEE726B37F70A6F7B770764E99",
Data = "encrypt[38ce517c95b011bbfc999f36d09e4feb92d22dd8,38ce517c95b011bbfc999f36d09e4feb92d22222]",
PaddedText = string:left(Data ++ ",",128,$0),
%%Data is "encrypt[38ce517c95b011bbfc999f36d09e4feb92d22dd8,38ce517c95b011bbfc999f36d09e4feb92d22222],0000000000000000000000000000000000000"
EncryptedText = crypto:block_encrypt(aes_cbc256, Key, Ivec, PaddedText),
%%Send to C code
```

And the c code

```c
unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)"586E36EEE726B37F70A6F7B770764E99";
unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char *)"1200000000000000";

EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv)
EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, buf, buf_len)
```

The error I get is

```
error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:539:
```

When I decrypt in Erlang it works fine and when I encrypt in C it also works fine with same Key and IV. 
Does it a Cipher mode mismatch. Though it looks correct to me.
Any pointers will be really useful.
Thanks

I figure out, the same data I Encrypted and decrypted in C and then made a Hex dump. The actual Encrypted data Erlang is senginh is 128 Bytes and the same data Encrypted by C openssl library is 144 bytes. That's normal cipher text are usually long. Here's the output.

The Erlang Binary returned after Enryption:

```
<<165,171,208,104,24,97,173,130,177,99,50,22,51,180,112,123,36,18,208,170,250,131,195,162,182,162,253,14,121,242,61,60,202,172,74,121,223,50,128,255,134,51,253,91,195,174,90,93,77,65,1,115,119,64,25,131,47,245,68,156,163,145,111,125,143,208,255,53,131,220,174,243,64,120,229,21,86,107,139,148,164,39,144,106,232,64,252,234,26,208,138,187,213,244,210,11,174,47,126,4,97,179,194,85,8,207,116,140,236,3,145,209,95,106,36,121,241,228,153,120,226,125,227,138,130,183,217,39>>
```

This is send by Erlang

```
    Encrypted =  128

a5 ab d0 68 18 61 ad 82 b1 63 32 16 33 b4 70 7b  
24 12 d0 aa fa 83 c3 a2 b6 a2 fd 0e 79 f2 3d 3c 
ca ac 4a 79 df 32 80 ff 86 33 fd 5b c3 ae 5a 5d 
4d 41 01 73 77 40 19 83 2f f5 44 9c a3 91 6f 7d 
8f d0 ff 35 83 dc ae f3 40 78 e5 15 56 6b 8b 94 
a4 27 90 6a e8 40 fc ea 1a d0 8a bb d5 f4 d2 0b 
ae 2f 7e 04 61 b3 c2 55 08 cf 74 8c ec 03 91 d1
5f 6a 24 79 f1 e4 99 78 e2 7d e3 8a 82 b7 d9 27
```

This is Output of Openssl (c) library fof the same data.

```
Encrypted = 144

a5 ab d0 68 18 61 ad 82 b1 63 32 16 33 b4 70 7b  
24 12 d0 aa fa 83 c3 a2 b6 a2 fd 0e 79 f2 3d 3c  
ca ac 4a 79 df 32 80 ff 86 33 fd 5b c3 ae 5a 5d 
4d 41 01 73 77 40 19 83 2f f5 44 9c a3 91 6f 7d 
8f d0 ff 35 83 dc ae f3 40 78 e5 15 56 6b 8b 94 
a4 27 90 6a e8 40 fc ea 1a d0 8a bb d5 f4 d2 0b  
ae 2f 7e 04 61 b3 c2 55 08 cf 74 8c ec 03 91 d1 
5f 6a 24 79 f1 e4 99 78 e2 7d e3 8a 82 b7 d9 27 
f7 01 c0 ed 95 e3 14 e5 d2 62 21 da a9 1d 2a e7
```

The last 16 bytes are missing from Erlang. Is there any other API I need to call from Erlang Crypto library?

Comment: `Data` looks like hexadecimal but has a comma in it, any hints about the comma? the encrypted output in hex would help.

Comment: Could you post the binary data just before sending it to C and right when you received in C?

Comment: Comma is just to separate 2 different keys(internal usage)

Comment: I can. I printed out the binary from Erlang and did a hex dump on c side. It is exactly same once received on the C side, but then when I pass to the decryption it fails. The only reason I see is different Cipher mode, as key and IV are exactly same.

Comment: I updated the exact Cipher Tect by Erlang and Openssl. The last 12 bytes are missing from Erlang. Does anyone know.

Comment: In case anyone comes here. By default Erlang disables the padding https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/crypto/c_src/crypto.c So make sure other side it is unpadded if directly using the openssl APIs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking at is a difference of *padding*. OpenSSL always pads using the PKCS#7 defined padding scheme. In Erlang you pad the plaintext with zero's (this is called zero padding) *before* encrypting using the cipher. The cipher itself doesn't pad (it seems).

As the plaintext is a multiple of 16 (128 bits, the block size of AES) a full block of padding - consisting of 16 bytes valued `10` in hex - is added to the plaintext by the OpenSSL routines.

So if you want to match the ciphertext you should use `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(0)`:

> `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding()` enables or disables padding. By default encryption operations are padded using standard block padding and the padding is checked and removed when decrypting. If the pad parameter is zero then no padding is performed, the total amount of data encrypted or decrypted must then be a multiple of the block size or an error will occur.

Comment: As there is explicit application level padding in Erlang it seems to me that there will also be application level unpadding. It doesn't make sense to pad an already padded plaintext. So I took this road instead of showing how to implement PKCS#7 padding in Erlang.

Comment: Thanks Maarten, make sense what you are saying, went through the above API and first tried using command line by encrypting with -nopad and decrypting with -nopad. It works. But using the above API it doesn't. Don't know if -nopad is calling some other API but the doc says the above what you mentioned. Before passing the context to decrypt APIs, I did ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new(); and EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx,0);

Comment: Could you try calling the `set_padding` function *after* the call to `init`? I presume the call to `init` will set it back to PKCS#7.

Comment: You are the man. Your sharp memory saved the day :). Thanks a lot